# .Net Core MVC RedirectToRoutePermanent does not redirect to matching action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on .Net core mvc project, and one action need to get three parameters ,
so i firstly created a new route in in **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "partner_detail",
                    pattern: "Partners/Detail/{id}/{name}/{location}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{title?}");
            });
```

and then there is a table which user can click on a specific partner and it will call to **partnercontroller**

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Partner.Name, "Detail", "Partners", new { id = Model.Partner.Id, name = Model.Partner.Name, location = Model.Location }, new { @class = "anchor-1" })
```

My action method is as follows,

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Detail(Guid id, string name, string location)
{
    string friendlyName = FriendlyUrlExtension.GetFriendlyTitle(name);
    string friendlyLocation = FriendlyUrlExtension.GetFriendlyTitle(location);

    if (!string.Equals(friendlyName, name, StringComparison.Ordinal) || !string.Equals(friendlyLocation, location, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        return this.RedirectToRoutePermanent("partner_detail", new { id = id, name = friendlyName, location = friendlyLocation });
    }

    return View();
}
```

I'm converting name and location to SEO friendly names and redirect it to above mentioned route,

Url is after formatted is

> `https://myhost:00001/Partners/Detail/571ee251-b342-4fd3-b3df-0471ed54078e/partner-1/location-7`

I have two questions to know from all you experts

1. When i use anchor tag to call to action it pass route values in query string, is there any way to pass them as route parameters?
2. Why RedirectToRoutePermanent doe not hit my action?

Is any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
I fixed it.
I used .net core anchor tag helper as follows,

```
<a controller="Partners" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@Model.Partner.Id" 
asp-route-name="@Model.Partner.Name" asp-route-location="@Model.Location">@Model.Partner.Name</a>
```

and remove route from startup.cs and added to controller action as attribute.

```
[Route("Partners/Detail/{id}/{name}/{location}", Name = "partner_detail")]
```

and anyone using anchor tag helper make sure your route parameter names are same as parameters in the route attribute.

about anchor tag helper [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)